# Spark2-submit failing with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am upgrading application from spark 1.6 to Spark 2 but Spark2-submit using pyspark is failing in Cloudera environment.

For this i have just updated spark2-submit from spark-submit but it is failing  unable to create Spark Context and giving below error. Looks like Spark 2 configuration is missing some property which is not allowing it to identify the staging location for storing python files.

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
File "/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
File "/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 182, in _do_init
File "/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 249, in _initialize_context
File "/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
File "/apps/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:368)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$distribute$1(Client.scala:481)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13.apply(Client.scala:629)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13.apply(Client.scala:627)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:627)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: hard to tell from the error message you posted, but you should be using the SparkSession with 2.x ... perhaps try re-coding the config application

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the logs..

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
```

your spark-submit binary is not able to locate spark home.

- either you have to su to a specific user for 
  eg: in emr you have to be hadoop which will set this for you automatically
- you can set `SPARK_HOME` before every invocation of spark-submit.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/
```